# Node: How to async await folder file reads

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, directory, filereader

How to read files asynchronously in node js, here is a simple function.

There are a lot of convoluted answers on the internet, does anyone agree if this is the simplest?

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  let data =  await readFiles('data/companies/');
  res.status(200).json(data);
}

// async file reader
function readFiles(dirname) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let data = {}

    fs.readdir(dirname, async function(err, filenames) {
      filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
        fs.readFile(dirname + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          }
          data[filename] = content;

          if (filenames.length === Object.keys(data).length) {
            resolve(data)
          }
        });
      });
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: [`readdir` is already async](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options). You likely just need to update your version of node

Comment: *does anyone agree if this is the simplest?* [that is opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Why not using `fs.promises` ? Look here [Node Doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Comment: can you then answer with a simple code snippet to read a directory of files to json using that method? The same as what the above does?

Comment: so you just want someone to do the work for you?

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner and easier using the built in promise support in `fs.promises`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const path = require('path');

// async file reader
async function readFiles(dirname) {
    const data = {};
    const files = await fsp.readdir(dirname);
    for (const filename of files) {
        const full = path.join(dirname, filename);
        const content = await fsp.readFile(full, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        data[filename] = content;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Or, if you want to run your file operations in parallel (at least to the limit of the thread pool), you might get slightly faster end-to-end performance like this:

```
// async file reader
async function readFiles(dirname) {
    const data = {};
    const files = await fsp.readdir(dirname);
    await Promise.all(files.map(async filename => {
        const full = path.join(dirname, filename);
        const content = await fsp.readFile(full, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        data[filename] = content;
    }));
    return data;
}
```

---

Also, this:

```
res.status(200).json(data);
```

can be replaced with:

```
res.json(data);
```

200 is already the default status so there is no reason to specify it.

Comment: @GreggOd - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Array.map function params are supposed to return a value, but your ```files.map``` async function has no return. Does it work? I suspect it means your Promise.all ends up getting passed an empty array.

Comment: @ColinMay - In my second code block, the `async` callback I'm passing to `.map()` returns a promise (all `async` functions return a promise).  `await Promise.all(files.map(...))` is awaiting that array of promises.  Because the OP wants the output of the function to an object (not an array) with properties as in `data[filename] = content`, this code is not using the resolved value of the `async` promise.  But it is using the promise that the `async` function returns to know when everything is done and thus to know when the `data` object is fully populated.

Comment: It's never occurred to me to think of ```async``` as essentially saying, "At the end of this function, add ```return promise```." That's a bit mind-blowy... Thanks, friend. 

Comment: @ColinMay - Yep, that's a good way to think of it.  And, actually the `return promise` happens at the first `await`, not at the end of the function.  The actual `return` statement is really like calling `resolve(value)` on the previously returned promise.